# og:image does not appear correctly

Tags: facebook, image, url

`og:image` is set correctly as well as link rel - i can know it is corrent because when i input the url in facebook debug, the correct image appears.
however, if i post the url in facebook, the image does not show - instead random images from the page are used...

here are the two lines i used in the HEAD section:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.lukulos.gr/images/previews/index.jpg"/>
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.lukulos.gr/images/previews/index.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Could you post the URL that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You may be having problems with the facebook cache.

Try and paste your page url here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and see what happens.

If it shows the correct image, then your problem is the facebook cache.